# How to fix this linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic error?

Tags: boot, grub2, dpkg, 19.10

```
Reading database ... 258850 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic (5.3.0-18.19+1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-18-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic package post-removal script subprocess return
ed error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Every time when i try to update or install a new package i face this error on my Ubuntu 19.10. During installing Ubuntu 19.10 i have faced some serious issue with my Grub boot loader. Because my pc has 3 os i had to manually partition the os. I have tried `sudo apt install -f` but the problem still persist.After running  `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
 Setting up linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic (5.3.0-46.38) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu12.2) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
Installation finished. No error reported.
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic (5.3.0-46.38) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda13
I: (UUID=491d3cd9-8ed4-4355-9277-c6a31bc65712)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic
```

What can i do to solve this problem?